# JavaScript: variable = variable || variable

Tags: javascript

I have absolutely no idea how this is called which is the reason why my searches failed miserably.

What does this code mean

```
var a = b || c;
```

I believe it's something like `a` will equal which ever is defined but.. I just have to be sure what it exactly does before I use it.

Comment: It is a boolean OR operation, a way you could search for it is "javascript double pipe operation", just for future reference :)

Comment: Yes, this is one of the things I wanted to find out, asking this question, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If b is defined, it will use b, if c is defined and b isn't, it will use c.  If you put it in parenthesis () it will return true/false.

Comment: what if both are defined, are there docs for this :?

Comment: In this context it makes sense to define "defined" more precisely.

Comment: @php_nub_qq: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_(.7C.7C)

Comment: if both are defined it will use b.  It stops evaluating as soon as its gets a valid (not null/false/undefined/0/empty string).

Comment: @BlakeA.Nichols but if I need to set a default value of `false` how would that work

Comment: var a = b || c || false;

Comment: *"If you put it in parenthesis () it will return true/false."* What?